# How do aggregate rows beneath text delimiter

Tags: sql-server

I have a poorly formatted CSV file I need to clean up.

There are no text specifiers in this CSV so I cannot use those to exclude the carriage returns and line feeds I have. My only option, it seems, is to aggregate records together using a STRING_AGG() clause or similar, until the next delimiting field in the same column. Sounds confusing, right?

I basically have a CSV that looks like this:

```
PRIMARY_IDENTIFIER | OTHER_COLUMNS
         1.abc     |     data
           def     |     NULL
           ghi     |     NULL
         2.abc     |     data2
         defghi    |     NULL
         3.zyx     |     data3
           wvu     |     NULL
```

When I need to find a way to concatenate the rows below each delimiting text artifact (the numeric at the beginning of PRIMARY_IDENTIFIER) so the data would look like:

```
PRIMARY_IDENTIFIER | OTHER_COLUMNS
     1.abcdefghi   |     data
     2.abcdefghi   |     data2
     3.zyxwvu      |     data3
```

I don't know how I'd implement this a kind of query where the delimiter is the same column that's broken up. The only thing I can ensure is that the first numeric characters are distinct. This problem is exacerbated by the fact I cant use any ORDER BY clause as two rows in the PRIMARY_IDENTIFIER columns could be the same, causing further discrepancies if thrown out of their current order.

I don't have much T-SQL to show for this example because, frankly, I don't know where to start. 
I have a vague notion I can use CTEs to at least identify the beginning of the fields I have to concatenate, but I don't know where to go from there.

```
SELECT COUNT(PRIMARY_IDENTIFIER) 
FROM MyTable
WHERE LEFT(PRIMARY_IDENTIFIER,1) LIKE '%[0-9]%'
```

Comment: The only the order of the rows is that they have the same order that they were entered into our system. In this awful case there isn't a date field in the CSV so that really doesn't work.

Comment: If the order of the CSV is valid (not that I have a way to verify that) do you think there's any way I could  make my concatenations without using an ORDER BY clause?

Comment: It seems to me this is a task not well suited for T-SQL. Since you already have this in a file could you open it, process it, and output the desired result using C# or your language of choice.

Comment: That's a good idea, I'll try that instead. T-SQL is a preference of mine but it can't do everything.